# Are these voltage regulators identical?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am creating a board based on a circuit diagram that just states "HT7333A" as identifier for a part.

Searching on octoparts.com, [I can find two different manufacturers](https://octopart.com/search?q=HT7333A&currency=USD&specs=0) that make pretty similar voltage regulators: Holtek and UMV

Spec sheets:

- [Holtek](https://www.angeladvance.com/HT73xx.pdf)
- [UMV](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2110111730_UMW-Youtai-Semiconductor-Co---Ltd--HT7333-A_C347191.pdf)

They look similar, but their internal circuit diagrams differ slightly.

Still, I assume that the identical serial numbers suggest that they are meant to be used equivalently?

Can I use them interchangeably?

Comment: My browser warns me about an unsecure connection when I click the Holtek datasheet link. You may want to find another source for it. And I'm afraid I can't read Chinese, so I can only get the gist of the UMV one. I would just skip both of these and go for one from a company I've heard of, personally.

Comment: As a pro I would recommend that you choose a regulator that is suitable for the design  - if you are a hobbyist and don't know how to do this then sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I am sure you will find they work perfectly well either way. Based on their pinouts, input, and output descriptions and limits, I would say they are equivalent. I wouldn't be surprised if they are the exact same IC, with just different manufacturers (who knows how they both *happened* to design the same chip lol)

Comment: Maybe it's the same factory line even...